# Select everything below an element

Tags: jquery, html, css, select

How would I pragmatically select all of the list items below noscript in jQuery?

```
<ul id="master">
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<noscript></noscript>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
<li class="item"></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [general sibling selector `~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators):

```
#master noscript ~ li {
    /* style */
}
```

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/HQ6tn/)

In jQuery: `$('#master noscript ~ li');`

Alternatively, you can also use [`.nextAll`](http://api.jquery.com/nextall/): `$('#master noscript').nextAll('li');`

Comment: Keep the CSS selector in jQuery, that was cool and worked http://jsfiddle.net/X3ET7/

Comment: @Sergio Alright, I'll put that back in. I just thought it was redundant :)

Comment: That was the reason of my `+1`:P